# How to run a module developed in Eclipse in a Python interactive prompt?

Tags: python, eclipse, python-3.x, pydev

Complete noob here wanting to learn Python.

I installed Python, then Eclipse, then PyDev.  Works great.  I created a couple of simple programs in Eclipse and they run fine there.

Now at the command prompt, I run `python.exe` and an interactive prompt opens.  How do I now run the foo.py module I developed earlier in Eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tu run this you have  to run

```
python foo.py
```

or as matijun said. if you want to import it:

```
>>> import foo
```

or

```
>>>from foo import *
```

Please note that your file path shuold be in PYTHONPATH.
To do this

```
import sys
sys.path.add("ur file path")
import foo
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to run

```
python.exe foo.py
```

Or, if it's a module, you can just import it:

```
>>> import foo
```

(but then its `__name__` won't be `__main__`, so if you have a special "If this is the main program" bit, it won't be executed)

Comment: Great.  If I wanted to import it and foo.py is in a completely different folder, how do I import it?

I've tried `>>> import c:\folder\folder\project\foo.py` but it comes back with invalid syntax

Comment: You have to import it through the module name (i.e.: import project.foo or from project import foo) and the proper folders need to be in the PYTHONPATH (in this case c:\folder\folder) -- note that the PYTHONPATH can be specified in the PYTHONPATH environment variable.